# on fadeout completed check if item exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im fading out a li element, but want to check if there any remaining li elements,
and set `basketIsEmpty` to `true` if there are no li elements...

the code below is setting `basketIsEmpty` to `true` always it seems? even though there are li elements. What is wrong?

```
$("li[data-li-frame-no='" + frameNo + "']").fadeOut(1000, function () {
 if ($("[data-li-frame-no]:visible").length) {
  basketIsEmpty = true;
 }  
});
```

Comment: `basketIsEmpty = $("[data-li-frame-no]:visible").length === 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is checking that there are elements with the attribute data-li-frame-no that ARE visible.  It sounds like you are asking to set that to true only when there are no visible.  In that case, just invert your boolean

```
if (!$("[data-li-frame-no]:visible").length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("[data-li-frame-no]:visible").length) {
    basketIsEmpty = true;
}
```

This should be `basketIsEmpty = false` because you conditioned if there are still remaining. If there are still remaining, it NOT empty (false)